# Find the natural number which is divisibled by another number

Tags: divisibility, natural-numbers

Let $n= \overline{a_1a_2a_3}$ ($a_1 \neq a_2$, $a_2 \neq a_3$, $a_3 \neq a_1$).

1/ How many possible values does $n$ have which is divisibled by $7$?

2/ How many possible values does $n$ have which is divisibled by $3$ or $4$?

3/ How many possible values does $n$ have which is divisibled by $3$ but not divisibled by $4$?

4/ How many possible values does $n$ have which is divisibled by $3$ and $4$?

Comment: Please explain your notation. Does the bar imply finite repetitions? Also please provide what you've tried to solve this.

Comment: @AlexR. Genearlly, the bar represents a three digit number i.e. $\overline{a_1a_2a_3}=100a_1+10a_2+a_3$ where all $a_i$ are distinct.

Comment: Yes, that right